# fillText method is not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to write a text on a canvas. Following is the code :

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="scaleChart" width="1500" height="500"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
var scaleCtx = document.getElementById("scaleChart").getContext("2d");
scaleCtx.fillStyle = 'rgba(40, 220, 140, 1)';
scaleCtx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 200);
scaleCtx.fillStyle = 'Black';
scaleCtx.font = '20px Calibri';
scaleCtx.fillText = ('00:00', 100, 50);
```

But no text is appearing. What wrong am I doing? Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/but0h85h/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple typo. Last line of JS should not have an equal sign in it.

```
var scaleCtx = document.getElementById("scaleChart").getContext("2d");
scaleCtx.fillStyle = 'rgba(40, 220, 140, 1)';
scaleCtx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 200);
scaleCtx.fillStyle = 'Black';
scaleCtx.font = '20px Calibri';
scaleCtx.fillText('00:00', 100, 50);
```